# Maya python commands: modelEditor (capture flag)

Tags: python, viewport, maya, pyside2

I want to save viewport into an image file and then use it as an icon in a PySide2.QtGui.QIcon, this is my code:

```
path = os.path.join(DIRECTORY, "{}.jpg".format(name))
cmds.modelEditor(self.viewport, e=True, capture=path)
icon = QtGui.QIcon(path)
```

self.viewport contains a previously created modelEditor, but this method has a delay in saving the file and when QIcon takes the path, the image file does not yet exist.

Can anybody help me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you can try to take a picture of the viewport with this :

```
def take_thumbnail():
    image = PATH_IMAGE
    cmds.refresh(currentView=True, fe='jpg', fn=image)
    return image

image = take_thumbnail()
QtGui.QIcon(image)
```

I tried quickly with a pyside UI, and it works.